# Can I modify and publish npm modules (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I use a module (scribe.js), published on npm, in my own module, but i did some modification to the original module and I would like to add as dependencies to my module this modified version, instead of the official one. I'm not really into legal issues about that and don't know if there is a standard accepted way to do this.

I can simply publish on a npm my modified version of the module or this is illegal/unkind/not-the-standard-way-to-do-that?

NB: All changes are not bug corrections, but graphics adjustment to scribe, to adapt it to my own environment, so it is not something likely (or meaningful) to be added to the original module.

Comment: Is your fork containing the changes on github or in a tarball somewhere?

Comment: not now. I'm still trying to understand the best way to publish that and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original [scribe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribe-js) is published under MIT license, what means you can basically do what you want with the package, even modify and sell it, but you must keep the indication of copyright and the license itself.

Comment: License read. This replies perfectly to my question. Thank you very much.